# Keyboard Backspace key not working but repeats when reconnecting USB

Tags: keyboard, usb, microsoft

I've been using, and enjoying, a Microsoft Sculpt Wireless keyboard for the past couple years. All of a sudden tonight the backspace key stopped working. Using the keyboard viewer, I can tell all the other keys are fine:

[image: all the keys except backspace work]

What's odd is if I disconnect and reconnect the USB receiver the viewer shows the backspace key like it's stuck. It's not. I've read some of the other answers on here about checking for crumbs and dust. Blown it out with air but haven't gone as far as disassembling it.

[image: plugin USB connector and backspace repeats]

[image: all the other keys work]

2013 iMac running 10.11.6 but it's also sadly happening on my MacBook Pro running the latest version of High Sierra. Love this keyboard, but wanted to see if anyone else has solved this without popping keys off.

I'm considering treating this as a challenge to improve my typing and spelling :)

Comment: Because it's happening on 2 different machines (iMac and MBP), it appears to be a hardware issue with the keyboard.  I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.

Comment: @fsb Not saying it's not off topic, but I'd say that there's not enough evidence to prove that it's not a software issue/something macOS related (though I'd suspect it's not.) I agree that it's probably a hardware failure, but I don't think that there's enough evidence to close it.

Comment: @jmy1000 is correct. I opened it because of several related software questions. fsb I could expand or change the direction of the question to include suggestions for remapping alternate keys to Backspace if want.

Answer (score -1):

Dude... your number pad is under something and the backspace key there is being pressed.

Just clear the number pad and it will start working.